# How to check programmatically which replica I'm connected to

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, c#

I have an AlwaysOn Availability Group on MS-SQLServer (2 replicas) and a C# application which sends queries to the Availability Group Listener.

How can I check which replica is responding my queries?

I know it's possible, because I've seen it in MS educational videos.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run SELECT @@SERVERNAME which will give you the current servername you are connected to.  Would this suit your requirements?

Comment: 12345 **Excellent!** (it should be 15 characters at least ;-)